# Cant' see a file I created with StreamWriter. C#

Tags: c#, file, io, directory, save

I'm a newbie.
I created a StreamWriter object to create and save some text in a file.
The writing goes on like this:

```
StreamWriter two = new StreamWriter(@"C:\two.txt", true);
two.WriteLine("Some Stuff");
two.Close();
```

And then I also added a StreamReader object so the program shows the content of the file on the console:

```
StreamReader two2 = new StreamReader(@"C:\two.txt");                                                        
Console.WriteLine(two.ReadToEnd());
two2.Close();
```

Every time I run the program, the output on the console is correct, and the text in the WriteLine method is appended. Yet if I visit C: with Windows File Explorer, the file two.txt isn't there.

Where is the file ?

P.S. If I change the address I want the file to be saved to, to let's say E: for example, everything works perfect, and I can see the file in E: with Windows File Explorer. So apparently there is something special with C: going on.

Comment: for c drive there is some security restriction, you better use user AppData folder for sving file

Comment: Always use Flush() method before closing a write file to make sure all data  is written.

Comment: I would rather say, always wrap IDisposable resources such as streams and readers in `using` statements.

Comment: The root directory of the C: drive is protected by UAC.  What is *supposed* to happen is that Windows recognizes your program to be compatible with UAC and you'll get an IOException.  But apparently it doesn't, the file gets redirected to a safe location in %appdata%.  Seems you built your program in an unusual way and it does not have a proper manifest.  How *that* happened is impossible to guess.  Don't monkey with the manifest, I guess.  And use Environment.GetFolderPath() to get a better directory to write to.

Comment: @HansPassant I just ran the application in debug mode from Visual Studio using the default settings.